# MediaCodec encoder produces Black & White videos in some devices

Tags: android, video, bitmap, android-mediacodec, yuv

I’m encoding a video from a set of Bitmaps by using the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec?hl=en) API.

As the minimum project API is 22, I’m using [COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible) to obtain a suitable encoder.

**The issue is that some users have reported that the output video result is in Black & White instead of in color.**

The bitmaps being pushed into the encoder are converted to YUV by using the below algorithm.
My best guess is that in the affected devices the encoder may be expecting a specific YUV format.

The question is, how to find which YUV format does the encoder expect? And, isn’t there a common YUV format which will work for all devices?

*Algorithm used to convert the bitmaps to YUV:*

```
void toYuv(const uint32_t* argb, int8_t* yuv, const uint32_t width, const uint32_t height)
{
    int32_t index_y = 0;
    int32_t index_uv = width * height;
    int32_t index = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            const int R = (argb[index] & 0x0000FF) >> 0;
            const int G = (argb[index] & 0xFF00) >> 8;
            const int B = (argb[index] & 0xFF0000) >> 16;

            const int Y = ((((R * 77) + (G * 150)) + (B * 29)) + 128) >> 8;
            const int U = (((((R * 127) - (G * 106)) - (B * 21)) + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            const int V = (((((R * -43) - (G * 84)) + (B * 127)) + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            yuv[index_y++] = static_cast<int8_t>((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));

            if (((j % 2) == 0) && ((index % 2) == 0))
            {
                yuv[index_uv++] = static_cast<int8_t>((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv[index_uv++] = static_cast<int8_t>((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is extremely unlikely this conversion is the issue. It is far more likely the issue is in the chroma subsampleing. Where are you converting from 4:4:4 to 4:2:0?

Comment: The way the video is encoded, is by converting each bitmap (from ARGB) into YUV420 by using the algorithm show in the question, and then enqueuing the resulting YUV420 byte array into the MediaCodec with queueInputBuffer

Comment: This code is difficult to follow (so many temp variables). It appears you are attempting a packed YUV. looking through `fourcc.org`, and ffmpeg `AV_PIX_FMT_*` I don't see any packed 4:2:0. 99% of encoders use `I420` planar 4:2:0. Is there a reason that wont work?